# How to position tooltip on the top of a barchart in rechart?

Tags: css, tooltip, bar-chart, recharts

**Problem:**
I have created a bar chart with a custom tooltip. Now What I need is to position tooltip on top of the bar not within the area of the chart. Like in this picture.

[image]

This is how It looks like now.

[image]

Here I am providing how I organize my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BarChart,
  Tooltip,
  Bar,
  Legend,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  Cell
} from "recharts";

import { Card, CardTitle, CardBody } from "reactstrap";

import "./SessionDuration.css";

const colors = ["#26a0a7", "#79d69f", "#f9ec86", "#ec983d"];

const data = [
  {
    name: "Page A",
    pv: 2400,
    amt: 2400
  },
  {
    name: "Page B",
    pv: 1398,
    amt: 2210
  },
  {
    name: "Page C",
    pv: 9800,
    amt: 2290
  },
  {
    name: "Page D",
    pv: 3908,
    amt: 2000
  }
];

const getTitleOfTooltip = (label) =>{
  if (label ===  0) {
    return "<=5 min";
  }
  if (label === 1) {
    return "5-30 min";
  }
  if (label === 2) {
    return "30-60 min";
  }
  if (label === 3) {
    return ">60";
  }
}
const getIntroOfPage = label => {
  if (label ===  0) {
    return "Page A is about men's clothing";
  }
  if (label === 1) {
    return "Page B is about women's dress";
  }
  if (label === 2) {
    return "Page C is about women's bag";
  }
  if (label === 3) {
    return "Page D is about household goods";
  }
};

class SessionDuration extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Card className="session-duration-card">
        <CardTitle className="session-duration-card-header">
          Session Duration
        </CardTitle>
        <CardBody>
          <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%" aspect={4.0 / 5.5}>
            <BarChart
              data={data}
              margin={{
                top: 3,
                right: 5,
                left: 5,
                bottom: 13
              }}
              barGap={10}
            >
              <Tooltip
                coordinate={{ x: 0, y: 150 }}
                content={<CustomTooltip />}
              />

              <Bar dataKey="pv" fill="#8884d8">
                {data.map((entry, index) => (
                  <Cell key={`cell-${index + 1}`} fill={colors[index]} />
                ))}
              </Bar>
            </BarChart>
          </ResponsiveContainer>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default SessionDuration;

const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
  if (active) {
    return (
      <div className="session-duration-tooltip">
        <p className="session-duration-tooltip-label">{getTitleOfTooltip(label)}</p>
        <p className="session-duration-tooltip-intro">
          {getIntroOfPage(label)}
        </p>
        <p className="session-duration-tooltip-desc">
          Anything you want can be displayed here.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return null;
};
```

Here I am providing my CSS file.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .session-duration-card {
    margin-top: 14.5%;
    margin-left: -44%;
    width: 190% !important;
    border-radius: none !important;
    height: 86%

  }

  .session-duration-card-header {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 6%
  }

  .session-duration-tooltip {
    width: 210%;
  }

  .session-duration-tooltip-label {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 308px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .session-duration-card {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 3.2%;
    width: 94.5%;
    border-radius: none !important;
  }

  .session-duration-card-header {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1666px) {
  .session-duration-card {
    margin-top: 11%;
    margin-left: -13%;
    width: 190% !important;
    height: 97%;
    border-radius: none !important;
  }

  .session-duration-card-header {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

I tried a lot to find a solution for my problem but I was unable to get it done can someone help me by modifying my code to get this work done. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

To solve this problem, will need  to get the height and width of each bar and tooltip.

1. Need two functions [onMouseMove](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Bar#onMouseMove) and [onMouseOut](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Bar#onMouseOut) to get the height
   and width of the **Bar** component.
2. Using `useState` to get and keep the height and width to the state, also place extra boolean to the state, to handle when the mouse is outside of the **Bar**. (So, to function we add object with two paramets *data* and *boolean* ).
3. In the **Tooltip** component, set the [position](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Tooltip#position) object for static values **X**, **Y** and using the state values, set the height and width.
4. Using `useEffect`, to find the `.recharts-tooltip-wrapper` class, to define the height and width of the DOM element.
5. Set styles for `.recharts-tooltip-wrapper`. (Rechart. js in `.recharts-tooltip-wrapper` has its own generated style, we need to keep some static style of the `.recharts-tooltip-wrapper` and add our).

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

##### SessionDuration.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BarChart, Tooltip, Bar, ResponsiveContainer, Cell } from 'recharts';

import { Card, CardTitle, CardBody } from 'reactstrap';

import './SessionDuration.css';

const colors = ['#26a0a7', '#79d69f', '#f9ec86', '#ec983d'];

const data = [
  {
    name: 'Page A',
    pv: 2400,
    amt: 2400,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page B',
    pv: 1398,
    amt: 2210,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page C',
    pv: 9800,
    amt: 2290,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page D',
    pv: 3908,
    amt: 2000,
  },
];

const getTitleOfTooltip = label => {
  if (label === 0) {
    return '<=5 min';
  }
  if (label === 1) {
    return '5-30 min';
  }
  if (label === 2) {
    return '30-60 min';
  }
  if (label === 3) {
    return '>60';
  }
};
const getIntroOfPage = label => {
  if (label === 0) {
    return "Page A is about men's clothing";
  }
  if (label === 1) {
    return "Page B is about women's dress";
  }
  if (label === 2) {
    return "Page C is about women's bag";
  }
  if (label === 3) {
    return 'Page D is about household goods';
  }
};

export const SessionDuration = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const tooltip = document.querySelector('.recharts-tooltip-wrapper');
    if (!tooltip) return;

    // Init tooltip values
    const tooltipHeight = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const tooltipWidth = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    const spaceForLittleTriangle = 10;

    // Rewrite tooltip styles
    tooltip.style = `
      transform: translate(${position?.data.x}px, ${position?.data.y}px);
      pointer-events: none;  position: absolute;
      top: -${tooltipHeight + spaceForLittleTriangle}px;
      left: -${tooltipWidth / 2 - position?.data.width / 2}px;
      opacity: ${position?.show ? '1' : 0};
      transition: all 400ms ease 0s;
    `;
  }, [position]);

  return (
    <>
      <Card className="session-duration-card">
        <CardTitle className="session-duration-card-header">
          Session Duration
        </CardTitle>
        <CardBody>
          <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%" aspect={4.0 / 5.5}>
            <BarChart
              data={data}
              margin={{
                top: 100, // for tooltip visibility
                right: 5,
                left: 5,
                bottom: 13,
              }}
              barGap={10}
            >
              <Tooltip
                cursor={false} // hide hover effect 'grey rectangle'
                position={{
                  // Static position
                  x: position?.data.x ?? 0,
                  y: position?.data.y ?? 0,
                }}
                content={<CustomTooltip />}
              />

              <Bar
                dataKey="pv"
                fill="#8884d8"
                // Handlers
                onMouseMove={data => setPosition({ data: data, show: true })}
                onMouseOut={data => setPosition({ data: data, show: false })}
              >
                {data.map((entry, index) => (
                  <Cell key={`cell-${index + 1}`} fill={colors[index]} />
                ))}
              </Bar>
            </BarChart>
          </ResponsiveContainer>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};

export default SessionDuration;

const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
  if (active) {
    return (
      <div className="session-duration-tooltip">
        <p className="session-duration-tooltip-label">
          {getTitleOfTooltip(label)}
        </p>
        <p className="session-duration-tooltip-intro">
          {getIntroOfPage(label)}
        </p>
        <p className="session-duration-tooltip-desc">
          Anything you want can be displayed here.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return null;
};
```

##### SessionDuration.css

```css
:root {
  --bg-color: hsl(270 3% 29% / 0.9);
}

.session-duration-tooltip {
  max-width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: aliceblue;
}

.session-duration-tooltip::after {
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  border-color: var(--bg-color) transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people asking for this feature here https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/222 and here https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/488. I came up with

#### Third working solution (with great help from @ЖнецЪ answer)

Unfortunately the problem with that answer is that you still have to hover the "bars" themselves, and mine are quite narrow, so I wanted it to show up regardless of if you are hovering the bar or the "cursor area", this solution allows the latter.

Basically:

- Get the active tooltip index from the full barchart (changes on the cursor area and not the specific bar)
- a useEffect hook grabs all the bars using the bar class `".recharts-bar-rectangle"` and grabs the current active one using the toolTipIndex, get's the height, and sets that to the tooltip Y-position.
- As before the tooltip is controlled by the internal x position but the y position is the height +/- some offset.

```
export default function BarChartCard(props) {
  const [activeBarIndex, setActiveBarIndex] = useState();
  const [toolTipYPosition, setToolTipYPosition] = useState({});


  useEffect(() => {
      const barCharts = document.querySelectorAll(".recharts-bar-rectangle");
      if (!barCharts || !activeBarIndex) return;
      // Init tooltip values
      const barChart = barCharts[activeBarIndex];
      setToolTipYPosition(barChart.getBoundingClientRect().height);
  }, [activeBarIndex]);

  return (
    <BaseCard>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Typography variant="h2">{props.title}</Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <ResponsiveContainer width={"100%"} height={300}>
        <BarChart
          barGap={0}
          data={props.data}
          margin={{
            top: 5,
            right: 30,
            left: 20,
            bottom: 5,
          }}
          onMouseMove={(e) => {
            setActiveBarIndex(e.activeTooltipIndex);
          }}
        >
          <Tooltip
            content={<CustomTooltip />}
            cursor={false}
            position={{ y: 170 - toolTipYPosition }}
            offset={-60}
            allowEscapeViewBox={{ x: true, y: true }}
          />
          <XAxis
            style={{
              fontSize: "1.125rem",
              fontFamily: "Cairo",
              fontWeight: 600,
            }}
            axisLine={false}
            tickLine={false}
            dataKey="date"
            tickFormatter={ReformatDateShortDayName}
          />
          <YAxis
            allowDecimals={false}
            style={{
              fontSize: "1.125rem",
              fontFamily: "Cairo",
              fontWeight: 600,
            }}
            dataKey="value"
            axisLine={false}
            tickLine={false}
          />
          <Legend
            style={{
              fontSize: "1.125rem",
              fontFamily: "Cairo",
              fontWeight: 600,
            }}
            iconType="circle"
            iconSize={6}
            align="right"
            verticalAlign="top"
            height={36}
            formatter={(value) => (
              <span
                style={{
                  color: "#CCC",
                  fontSize: "1.125rem",
                  fontWeight: 600,
                  fontFamily: "Cairo",
                }}
              >
                {value}
              </span>
            )}
          />
          <Bar
            barSize={10}
            dataKey="value"
            name={props.legendText}
            fill="#EFC92B"
          />
        </BarChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </BaseCard>
  );
}
```

#### A hacky solution

based on some other implementation and answers out there:

```
const [barGraphData, setBarGraphData] = useState({})

return (
<BarChart barGap={0} data={props.data} margin={{
            top: 5,
            right: 30,
            left: 20,
            bottom: 5
            }}>
    <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />}
    cursor={{ fill: 'transparent' }}
    position={{ y: barGraphData.height + 40}}
    offset={-60}
    />
    <XAxis />
    <YAxis />
    <Legend />
    <Bar 
       barSize={10} 
       dataKey="value" 
       fill="#EFC92B" 
       onMouseOver={(data)=> {
            setBarGraphData(data)
            }}
       onMouseLeave={(data) => {
            setBarGraphData(data)
            }}
            />
</BarChart>
)
```

So basically:

- Have a static y-value, in this case I'm doing the height of the bar + some offset (at least I think it's the height of the bar). But this one could be static as well.
- Add an offset to the tooltip, I had to do this otherwise it would not be on top of the bar but right shifted 60 pixels.
- Let the x coordinate be handled by recharts.

As you can see from my code, I used a custom tooltip according to the recharts documentation

```
const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Fragment>
            {active && payload?.length >= 1 &&
                <Card className={classes.toolTip}>
                    <CardContent className={classes.toolTipContent}>
                        <Typography className={classes.toolTipLabel}>{label}</Typography>
                        <Typography className={classes.toolTipValue}>{payload[0].payload.value}</Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                </Card>
            }
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

But this is just for formatting / style, it should work with the default one as well.

Unfortunately this only seems to work when you hover the actual "Bar" and not the full area as defined by the "cursor".

### Second hacky solution, which works for the full cursor area

This led me to a second solution which unfortunately gives an warning

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`BarChartCard`) while rendering a different component (`label`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `label`, follow the stack trace as described in ...
```

The code to create get it going is here, any comment on how to make this work would be awesome!

```
export default function BarChartCard(props) {
  const [barGraphData, setBarGraphData] = useState({});
  const [activeBarIndex, setActiveBarIndex] = useState({});
  const [toolTipYPosition, setToolTipYPosition] = useState({});

  return (
    <BaseCard>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Typography variant="h2">{props.title}</Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <ResponsiveContainer
        width={"100%"}
        height={300}
      >
        <BarChart
          barGap={0}
          data={props.data}
          margin={{
            top: 5,
            right: 30,
            left: 20,
            bottom: 5,
          }}
          onMouseMove={(e) => {
            setActiveBarIndex(e.activeTooltipIndex)
          }}
        >
          <Tooltip
            content={<CustomTooltip />}
            cursor={false}
            position={{ y: -toolTipYPosition + 170}}
            offset={-60}
            allowEscapeViewBox={{ x: true, y: true }}
          />
          <XAxis
            style={{
              fontSize: "1.125rem",
              fontFamily: "Cairo",
              fontWeight: 600,
            }}
            axisLine={false}
            tickLine={false}
            dataKey="date"
            tickFormatter={ReformatDateShortDayName}
          />
          <YAxis
            allowDecimals={false}
            style={{
              fontSize: "1.125rem",
              fontFamily: "Cairo",
              fontWeight: 600,
            }}
            dataKey="value"
            axisLine={false}
            tickLine={false}
          />
          <Legend
            style={{
              fontSize: "1.125rem",
              fontFamily: "Cairo",
              fontWeight: 600,
            }}
            iconType="circle"
            iconSize={6}
            align="right"
            verticalAlign="top"
            height={36}
            formatter={(value) => (
              <span
                style={{
                  color: "#CCC",
                  fontSize: "1.125rem",
                  fontWeight: 600,
                  fontFamily: "Cairo",
                }}
              >
                {value}
              </span>
            )}
          />
          <Bar
            label={(e) => {
              if(e.index === activeBarIndex){
                setToolTipYPosition(e.height)
              }
              return null;
            }}
            barSize={10}
            dataKey="value"
            name={props.legendText}
            fill="#EFC92B"
            onMouseOver={(data) => {
              setBarGraphData(data);
            }}
            onMouseLeave={(data) => {
              setBarGraphData(data);
            }}
          />
        </BarChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </BaseCard>
  );
}
```